# pmc-cloud-tools can't be used in k8s worker node

Tags: performance, kubernetes, perf

I try to use the pmc cloud tools(https://github.com/brendangregg/pmc-cloud-tools) to check the performance issue in my k8s worker node, but seems the worker nodes doesn't support it, could you help review and provide some suggestions? thanks.

it works in compute
[perf stat works in compute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/za4G4.png)

```
 Performance counter stats for 'sleep 1':

          0.69 msec task-clock                       #    0.001 CPUs utilized             
             1      context-switches                 #    1.446 K/sec                     
             0      cpu-migrations                   #    0.000 /sec                      
           175      page-faults                      #  252.976 K/sec                     
     1,440,998      cycles                           #    2.083 GHz                       
       780,218      instructions                     #    0.54  insn per cycle            
       152,536      branches                         #  220.503 M/sec                     
         7,169      branch-misses                    #    4.70% of all branches           

   1.002242560 seconds time elapsed

   0.000000000 seconds user
   0.002007000 seconds sys
```

one example:

```
    compute-205-8-1 ~]# ./pmc-cloud-tools-master/pmcarch
K_CYCLES   K_INSTR      IPC BR_RETIRED   BR_MISPRED  BMR% LLCREF      LLCMISS     LLC%
18215142   15155790    0.83 3086984568   27051306    0.88 149647788   14286326   90.45
18694421   15878877    0.85 3252902583   27742819    0.85 151033667   14121333   90.65
18353039   15331153    0.84 3127338178   27591171    0.88 150433721   13644983   90.93
17913093   14870389    0.83 3044521196   27157109    0.89 146226102   13718501   90.62
```

but not work in k8s worker node that deploy in the compute. several key counters shows not supported.
[perf stat in k8s worker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MnR7.png)

```
 Performance counter stats for 'sleep 1':

          0.73 msec task-clock                #    0.001 CPUs utilized          
             1      context-switches          #    1.365 K/sec                  
             0      cpu-migrations            #    0.000 /sec                   
            61      page-faults               #   83.256 K/sec                  
           <not supported>      cycles                                                      
           <not supported>      instructions                                                
           <not supported>      branches                                                    
           <not supported>      branch-misses                                               

   1.001525983 seconds time elapsed

   0.001651000 seconds user
   0.000000000 seconds sys
```

there is no output in k8s worker node.

```
worker-1 ~]# ./pmc-cloud-tools-master/pmcarch 
K_CYCLES   K_INSTR      IPC BR_RETIRED   BR_MISPRED  BMR% LLCREF      LLCMISS     LLC%
```